# How to create a generic table template for BackboneJS use

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

So my template thus far:

```
<script id="table-row" type="x-handlebars-template">
    <tr>
        {{#each this}}
            <td>{{.}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
</script>
```

And my render code:

```
that.collection.each(function(model){
     var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#table-row').html() );
     that.table.append(template(model.toJSON()));
});
```

Any my dummy data collection:

```
this.collection = new Backbone.Collection([
      {name: "Tim", age: 5},
      {name: "Ben", age: 26},
      {name: "Rob", age: 55}
    ]);
```

Now, how can I create a template that can output as many `<td>`s as there are object keys in my Model? ie. I have 'name' and 'age' now, but what I add 'height', I have to specifically update this template, how can I create a generic table row template?

Comment: You might want to move the `var template = Handlebars.compile(...)` outside the iterator, there's no need to repeat those three operations on every iteration. And keep in mind that JavaScript objects are not ordered so you can't depend on the keys coming out in any particular order; that means that you will have to specify the desired keys and their order separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a custom Handlebars helper to iterate over object keys. I haven't used it but something [like this](https://gist.github.com/1371586) should do the trick.

Here's the code from that link:

```
// HELPER: #key_value
//
// Usage: {{#key_value obj}} Key: {{key}} // Value: {{value}} {{/key_value}}
//
// Iterate over an object, setting 'key' and 'value' for each property in
// the object.
Handlebars.registerHelper("key_value", function(obj, fn) {
    var buffer = "",
        key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            buffer += fn({key: key, value: obj[key]});
        }
    }

    return buffer;
});
```

Comment: That will work but `for (key in obj)` is not guaranteed to iterate in any particular order so this isn't terribly useful.

Comment: So how do you suggest to handle the matter?

Comment: That's true. If it needs to be in a specific order then how about listing all the keys you know about manually and then putting this loop at the end as a catch-all? You could modify the helper to take an array of keys to exclude.